# IE6 specific javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have a validation script that absolutely positions a series of `<span>`s using positioning. However, the positioning is off by about 10px to the right (aka 10 more pixels need to be added to the right) in IE6. I was wondering if I could jQuery to detect IE6 and add 10 more pixels to the right. This is the code I have:

```
if ( ($item.val() == nameOrig) || ($item.val() == "") && ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)>6) ) {

        $(wrong).appendTo('body').hide().fadeIn("normal").css({
            'top' : position.top + 'px',
            'right' : ($item.width()*1.5) + parseFloat($item.css('padding-left'), 10) + parseFloat($item.css('margin-left'), 10) + parseFloat($item.css('padding-right'), 10) + extraSpace +'px'
        });

        $item.addClass('textError');
    }
```

Basically, I couldn't figure out how to add 10 more pixels to IE6, so I wanted to refrain the `<span>` (stored in variable `wrong`) from even showing up in IE6. But even that didn't work (aka, it showed up in IE6...ugh).

EDIT: if someone could just explain to me why the above code works for IE6 while it specifically says in the `if statement` to have the script work **only** if it's IE > 6

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find the issue is the old Box Model problem, basically IE uses a different model for where padding, margins, etc are in relation to the entity width/height. It's very well documented on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

I'd suggest having some additional/different CSS entries that are only processed for IE6 that take this into account, i.e. by making the width larger. You can do that via conditional comments, also documented [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment).

Comment: Do you know why my script works for IE6 though? It shouldn't append the `<span>` if the user has IE6 enabled (from the if statement). So why does it??

Comment: Try using this as the check for IE 6 rather that your condition: `($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) < 7)`